# Can't connect to my 11g db after trying to install Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I am running Oracle 11g, and was trying to install oracle 12c.
Somehow, this has messed up my oracle 11g, even if I installed it in a seperate directory. Everything was working fine, until I rebooted my computer, after trying to install 12c (which by the way never finished installing cus of errors). So I deleted 12c again, but left with a 11g that won't work
I get the following error:

```
 ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

My tnsnames.ora looks like this:

```
    LOCAL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = XE)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
  )
```

When I run a lsnrctl status, all looks fine:

```
    LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 16-FEB-2017 15:21:18

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                16-FEB-2017 13:00:11
Uptime                    0 days 2 hr. 21 min. 6 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/romio-ThinkPad-S3-Yoga-14/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=romio-ThinkPad-S3-Yoga-14)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

When I check the status for the Oracle instance, all looks good as well
I have tried to kill all Oracle processes after deleting the 12c, and restart them, but that didn't seem to help.
Is there another way I can check for Oracle processes than:

```
ps aux | grep oracle
```

Maybe there are some processes (from 12c) that I don't see. 
Any help is appreciated, I'm out of attempts and ideas

By the way, I am running on ubuntu

Comment: Did the 12c installation overwrite your central `listener.ora`, perhaps? With the default settings your database should still have tried to register against the listener (assuming the DB is up!), and you should be able to access it via its service name instead of its SID. But that `status` output isn't showing the DB service name - which suggests the DB isn't actually running, or is unable to register for some reason. Do the listener or DB alert logs shed any light?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The listener.ora looks fine, the 12c did not change anything in that, and the logs do not reveal anything of help. I noticed when trying to start the database via sqlplus as sysdba, I get this error: 


ORA-09925: Unable to create audit trail file. Suggestions on this fix is altering the audit_file_dest parameter, but how can I do this when I am not able to access the database?

Comment: This is getting more involved and off-topic for this site. Sounds like that is your real problem though, and maybe removing 12c deleted more than you thought. You may be able to `startup nomount` and see, and possibly modify (perhaps via creating a pfile), the audit dest - creating the directory structure it expects might be enough. But there may well be other things similarly broken. Hopefully your data files are still there. Do you have an OS backup you can revert to, if it comes to that?

Comment: Yes, I am running on a local database, and not the production, thank god. I think the solution for now will be to completely remove and reinstall 11g

Comment: I have had this same issue with installing Oracle 12 on a machine that previously had an Oracle 10G client. Check your windows path, make certain that all of the Oracle 11 entries are first. Run LSNRCTL STATUS from a command line and verify that the listener is running properly. I use Windows, log onto the server , from the prompt: SET ORACLE_SID=SIDNAME <nl> sqlplus / as sysdba This will allow you to connect  to your DB, if it is up and running.